# How to "define" a global var (uniqueness guaranteed)

Tags: php, global-variables

by define I mean using `define` function.
What I want to know is can I shorten this:

`$GLOBALS['MY_VAR']`  to  `MY_VAR` ... and use it in any scope! (not having to use `global $myvar;` in functions).

**EDIT**:
example: `print_r(MY_VAR['somekey']);`  gives error!

**EDIT**:
I understand it makes a constant variable, but isn't it a constant pointer to the array? I thought arrays are mutable in php?

Comment: Did you bother checking the PHP site for http://php.net/define? C'mon... you've put the answer right in your question...

Comment: He did as for "Uniqueness Guaranteed", which might remove the collision with the duplicate. But I'm not  PHP guru, so I can't really determine the appropriate action to take. Edit and move on...

Comment: $_SESSION is also a possibility: $_SESSION['myVarName'] = 'something'

Comment: I'm a C/C++ programmer, who is a bit lost is the way things work in php.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this :

```
define("CONSTANT","anything");
```

and you can use `CONSTANT` anywhere in any scope.

### example :

```
define("CONSTANT","123abc321");
function test(){
   return CONSTANT;
}
echo test(); //echoes 123abc321
```

### But

Note that you can't assign an array to a constant value.

Comment: can the value be an array tho??? that's my question

Comment: no, you cant set the value of a constant to an array

Answer (score 0):

Define refers to a constant and not a global. Constants can be used anywhere. Below is how you would use it with the example you gave.

```
define( 'MY_VAR', $GLOBALS['MY_VAR'] );
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/define

Comment: MY_VAR = array('aa' => '11', 'bb' => '22');  does not work!!

Comment: @Mack you cant assign an array to a constant

Comment: Also once you set a constant (using define) it can't be changed either so MY_VAR = anything wouldn't work.

Comment: if you use C/C++ define works differently. anyway print_r(MY_VAR['somekey']); does not work!!

Comment: Arrays aren't a valid value type for constants

Comment: @NathanDawson now how do you access the elements? MY_VAR['key'] gives error!

Comment: That's because MY_VAR['key'] would mean MY_VAR is an array. You would use MY_VAR. E.g. `echo MY_VAR;`

Answer (score 0):

Hm, is it always a constant? I guess a better way is you build your own token. If you do so, you can access from anywhere your token and edit, read or change the values within this token.

For your needs, build a token class (*just copy and paste it to file named MyTokenHolder.php*):

```
class MyTokenHolder
{
    protected static $_sessionkey = "BE SURE TO OVERRIDE THIS KEY";

    //Define your values here
    public $Username;
    public $UserID;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION[self::$_sessionkey]))
        {
            $token = unserialize(base64_decode($_SESSION[self::$_sessionkey]));
            //see above public params
            $this->Username     = $token->Username;
            $this->UserID       = (int)$token->UserID;
        }
    }

    public function SaveToSession()
    {
        $_SESSION[self::$_sessionkey] = base64_encode(serialize($this));
    }

    public static function DestroySession()
    {
        unset($_SESSION[self::$_sessionkey]);
    }
}
```

Now, you can set the values, which are defined within the token:

```
//Set Values
$token = new MyTokenHolder();
$token->Username = 'test';
$token->UserID = 99;
$token->SaveToSession();
```

And also you can read your values from token.

```
//Read Values 
$token = new MyTokenHolder();
echo $token->UserID;
echo $token->Username;
```

Test your self here - SQL Fiddle: http://ideone.com/jj7r6l